# Set Array to Varchar

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to set Array to Varchar(50)?

I am using C# and SQL Server.

```
unsigned char un32DBSeqNumber[31]

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommandType",un32DBSeqNumber[1]);
```

I would set `un32DBSeqNumber[1]` to `un32DBSeqNumber[31]` to `varchar`.

Comment: Can you show us the entire method you are editing please?

Comment: What is the type of `un32DBSeqNumber`? `byte[]`? `char[]`? What does it contain? Your question is not so much how you get it into a `VARCHAR(50)`, but how you convert that array to a `string`. `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` might be a start -- but that's making assumptions about the encoding.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Edited - unsigned char

Comment: @Safa: not possible -- C# has no `unsigned char` type, nor even an `unsigned` keyword. What's the *managed* type of the array? It should be `byte[]` if it's a straightforward translation of an unmanaged type. Either that or this code isn't C# at all, but C++/CLI. In which case, tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I would set un32DBSeqNumber[1] to un32DBSeqNumber[31] to varchar.

It's not entirely clear what that means, do you want to convert the range of chars into a string?

```
string un32DBSeqNumberStr = new String(ubn32DBSeqNumber, 1, 30);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommandType", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = un32DBSeqNumberStr;
```

Comment: Thanks - but un32DBSeqNumber is Unsigned and String is Signed .

Comment: i use this code
`String un8Params = new String (reinterpret_cast<char *>(un32DBSeqNumber),1,30);`

but this code is a very bad.